# NUnit Test Adapter Category filter on TFSBuild

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, tfsbuild

I wonder if it is possible to run categorized NUnit tests on TFSBuild (Visual Studio Online). I've installed the [NUnit Test Adapter](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.3) WithFramework NuGet Package [v1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework/). Tests are executing fine on the build server but when I add a "test case filter" (TestCategory=Unit) in the build definition, no tests are running. I'm pretty sure that my tests are setup with this Category attribute ([Test, Category("Unit")]).

My understanding was that the NUnit Test Adapter would map TestCategory to Category as explained in this [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikramagrawal/archive/2012/07/23/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-rc-using-testcasefilter.aspx). In the [release notes](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapterReleaseNotes&r=2.6.3) of the NUnit Visual Studio Test adapter it also states:

> Bug Fixes: #13 Category attribute not working with TFS test case
>   filter

Anyone else has experience with this?

[image: test case filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have configured a "Version control path to custom assemblies" on your build controller and have an old NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.dll at that location, this dll will take precedence over the NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.dll in your project.

I have removed this old dll to work with the NuGet package and the TestCategory filter is working just fine now!